# unable to install the php extension mcrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt

I tried installing the php extension mcrypt 1.0.2 
This extension is so that you can have mcrypt on a php version above 7.
The project that i'm trying to run is old and it needs mcrypt.

I followed this tutorial:

First, you should download the suitable version for your system from here: https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt/1.0.3/windows

Later, you should copy php_mcrypt.dll under ../xampp/php/ext/ and you should enable extension like extension=mcrypt from xampp/php/php.ini

This did not solve my problem. 
I'm still getting the message: PHP mcrypt extension is required.

Is this a common problem or did i do something wrong.

Using php 7.2.24

Comment: What OS are you working on? I'm guessing windows (based on the he URL) but please confirm.

Comment: You could slap VirtualBox on your machine and crank up a *nix distro downgraded to PHP 5.6 ?

Comment: Where do you get the message from?

Comment: I work on Windows 10. The message pops up in cmd or the shell from xampp.